# Changing current post image uls with a function

Tags: images, url-rewriting

I've changed my wp-content folder to a folder called stuff and am trying to change my image urls in existing posts with a function rather than a SQL query...

I've placed this in my function.php hoping it would work, but the images are still using the 'wp-content' folder?

```
define('WP_UPLOADSURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
add_filter( 'pre_option_upload_url_path', function( $upload_dir_uri ){
    return str_replace( WP_UPLOADSURL . '/wp-content/', WP_UPLOADSURL . '/stuff/', $upload_dir_uri );
});
```

Thanks to a suggestion below, `the_content` works!

```
define('WP_UPLOADSURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $upload_dir_uri ){
    return str_replace( WP_UPLOADSURL . '/wp-content/', WP_UPLOADSURL . '/stuff/', $upload_dir_uri ); /* Again Change stuff */
});
```

Comment: That filter will have no effect on post content - you need `the_content`

Comment: so `add_filter('the_content', function(...` would do it?

Comment: Give it a go, it should in theory.

Comment: still not working with `the_content`

Comment: Are the URLs you're trying to replace within content output by `the_content` function?

Comment: oops, the content I was checking was output via a metabox! thanks all.